# Laravel Passport api:auth middleware "Function name must be a string"

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-6

We're currently using Laravel version 6 and Passport version 8.1. We are experiencing something weird when using the `auth:api` middleware. When we call the middleware it always returns an [error](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2103eb7ccfbb6798e9078d82e0ebffcf87d95b14/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php#L172).

> "message": "Function name must be a string", "exception":
>   "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError", "file":
>   "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
>   "line": 172

We tried disabling all middleware and also calling the middleware in every possible way. When removing the `auth:api` middleware it works perfectly fine, but of course, that is not useful without authentication.

We found a similar issue on Laracasts [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/weird-function-name-must-be-a-string-with-authapi) but with no linked solution. Maybe someone here can set us in the right direction?

Comment: Could you share your routes/api.php file

Comment: I suggest adding `if (!method_exists($pipe, $this->method) && !is_string($pipe)) { dd($pipe); }` just before the error line to see what value it's actually using. And confirm that you have `'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,` in your `App\Http\Kernel.php`.

Comment: @Thomas the $pipe contains the Authmanager

Comment: Do you mean the class I mentioned in my last comment? Can you also check what value `$this->method` has?

Comment: @Thomas i compared the source of us to laravel on github and we were indeed missing the 'auth' route middleware. That seems to do it.

Comment: Glad I could help. Do you think that was enough to get the bounty? didn't really give a "reputable" source...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is most often related to a missing middleware.

The `auth` middleware has to be registered in [`App\Http\Kernel`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php#L54):

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    // ...
];
```

The [`\App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php) class should extend `\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate` which contains the actual logic.